# Flutter Alert Dialog Not Centered

Tags: flutter, flutter-alertdialog

I'm creating a Flutter mobile application. I have a Scaffold with a Drawer that is Centered in the App Like This:

> Centered Drawer: https://ibb.co/s5BMdNM

When The User Taps on the 2nd ListTile which is "Filter Character / Choose Categories", an AlertDialog popups. The Problem is the Alert Dialog isn't Centered neither vertically nor horizontally in the Landscape Orientation, and It's not centered vertically in the Portrait one.

> Landscape AlertDialog: https://ibb.co/GtdJ2jZ
>
> Portrait AlertDialog: https://ibb.co/HH6vQbx

I've tried calculating the percentage of the misplacement and adding it as a padding to the right, it worked when the Device Orientation was LandscapeRight, but was misplaced again when the orientation became LandscapeLeft.

> Right Adjusted: https://ibb.co/h9K0YB3
>
> Left Misplaced: https://ibb.co/JykZ67x

I've Searched but currently there's a problem getting the Device's true orientation.

So can anyone help me centering the AlertDialog, or tell me why it isn't centered? Thanks in Advance.

Summarized Drawer's Code:

```
Scaffold(
key: scaffoldKey,
backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
body: _getScaffoldBody(homePageState, context),
drawer: Center(
child: Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9 > 375
      ? 375
      : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9 > 58.0 * 6
      ? 58.0 * 6 // 58 * Number of List Tiles
      : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
  ),
  child: ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    children: <Widget>[
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Filter Characters / Choose Categories'),
            trailing: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              showCategoriesDialg(homePageState, context);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Showing AlertDialog's Code:

```
Future showCategoriesDialg(State<HomePage> homePageState, BuildContext context) async {
  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap a button!
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        scrollable: true,
        content: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 200,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: categories.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return CheckboxListTile(
                title: Text(categories.values.elementAt(index).titleEn),
                value: categories.values.elementAt(index).checked,
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                  homePageState.setState(() {
                    categories.values.elementAt(index).checked = newValue;
                  });
                },
                controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: @pskink I tried replacing the Container with this to test:

```content: ListBody( children: <Widget>[ Text('This is a demo alert dialog.'), Text('Would you like to approve of this message?'), ], ),```

but it still isn't centered.

Comment: I think it has to do with 2 popups (the Drawer and the AlerDialog) in front of each other?

Comment: @pskink Unfortunately No =(

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can get the device orientation

```
 void main() => runApp(MyApp());

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

   Widget _portraitView(){

     // Return Your Widget View Here Which you want to Load on Portrait Orientation.
     return Container(
    width: 300.00,
     color: Colors.green,
     padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
     child: Text(' Portrait View Detected. ',
             textAlign: TextAlign.center,  
             style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white)));
   } 

    Widget _landscapeView(){

     // // Return Your Widget View Here Which you want to Load on Landscape      Orientation.
     return Container(
     width: 300.00,
     color: Colors.pink,
     padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
     child: Text(' Landscape View Detected.',
             textAlign: TextAlign.center,  
             style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white)));
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
         home: Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text('Detect Device Screen Orientation')),
         body: OrientationBuilder(
           builder: (context, orientation) {
           return Center(

             child: orientation == Orientation.portrait 
             ? _portraitView() 
             : _landscapeView() 

                 );
            }
           )
          )
       );
   }
 }
```

after you get the correct device orientation you can place your widgets accordingly. 
and dont use fixed values as a height and width
use always 
     MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * percentageYouWant
     MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5

Etc.

Hope will help you